# Is a dynamic cast appropriate here?

Tags: c++

Say in a game, we have Entities that communicate with each other. Say a player collides with an Item and now, that item should be placed in his `std::vector<Item*>`

When the player receives the collision message, he receives the item as an Entity*. Would it then be appropriate for the player to cast it as an item, and if the cast succeeds, to push the item into the inventory?

Even if the game sent him a HIT_ITEM message, he would still need to cast it to push it in.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` helps you check the validity while performing downcasting.

It returns a `NULL` or throws an exception(`std::bad_cast` for References)if the pointer or the reference cannot be safely downcasted.

It is unclear to say unless you show us the class structures.

Answer (score 2):

If you can satisfactorily answer these questions for yourself, then yes.

- Why does the player receive the collision message with an Entity* rather than an Item*?
- at the point of the potential cast, are you SURE it'll be of dynamic type item? What if it isn't ?
- Is there any way you could relatively painlessly redesign your code to avoid the cast?

Anyway, don't be dogmatic. If in the current circumstances a downcast is more convenient than other things, do it. IMHO

Comment: Could you give an example of a redesign that could do this without a cast? My Message class has an Entity* that is why everything is sent this way. Should my Message class contain a pointer to every Entity type in my game?

Comment: @Milo: It shouldn't. I don't know your internals. There are hundreds of patterns that serve these purposes - each applicable in its own case... However, in my experience as far as general purpose messages are concerned, there are usually downcasts

Comment: @Milo:  An example would be double dispatch with a visitor for adding the item to the player inventory. Search for "double dispatch", it should give you enough examples.

Answer (score 0):

The main question you should ask yourself is- could I just make this a virtual function on Entity? In this case, I would probably say "no", because it doesn't make sense for non-Items to know or care about what you're gonna do with an Item. So `dynamic_cast` probably is the right solution- you can safely handle the case of `null` coming back and it keeps the other derived classes from having to know anything about Item.

Answer (score -1):

How about adding a type member together with a GetType() function to the base class? This is how I usually solve those "casting" problems.

In addition don't forget to turn on RTTI if you are going to use dynamic_cast (please ignore it this was obvious).

Comment: Even if I know the type, I can't just shove an Entity* into a vector of Item* can I?

Comment: @Milo: What is the relationship between `Entity` and `Item`?

Comment: Even if you knew the `Entity` message was a `Item` using a `GetType` function, you'd still need to cast it - granted though, you'd be able to `static_cast` it which would be a bit quicker.

Comment: Definitely no, no, no. GetType -> typeid(). You're not solving any problem here, adding your own GetType function is worthless.

Comment: @DeadMG Imagine coding guidelines were you are not allowed to use RTTI. Happened to me, maybe to you also. So it is far away from worthless.